# check boxes states android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, radio-button, checkbox

Am trying to get the count of how many check boxes are selected and if you de-select one, it's suppose to update the counter to -1......So if i select 4 check boxes and it says "check less" = count 4...then i pick 3 and the counter=3..this is what i have:
// ---CheckBox 1---
       final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

```
   // ---CheckBox 2---
   final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

   // ---CheckBox 3---

   final CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);


   // ---CheckBox 4---

   final CheckBox checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

   Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           if (checkBox.isChecked())
               count++;
           if (checkBox.isPressed())
               count--;
           if (checkBox2.isChecked())
               count++;
           if (checkBox2.isPressed())
               count--;
           if (checkBox3.isChecked())
               count++;
           if (checkBox3.isPressed())
               count--;
           if (checkBox4.isChecked())
               count++;
           if (checkBox4.isPressed())
               count--;
           if (count == pubsSelected){
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Screen2.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
       }
           else if (count < pubsSelected)
               DisplayToast("Pick more pubs/holes");
           else if (count > pubsSelected)
               DisplayToast("Pick less pubs/holes");
       }

   });
```

}

Comment: Instead of using different variables for CheckBox, you can have an array of CheckBoxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do this instead:

```
if (checkBox.isChecked())
{
    count++;
}else
{
    count--;
}

 if (checkBox2.isChecked())
{
    count++;
}else
{
    count--;
}
```

Comment: @Maurice How do I this if my `CheckBox` number in my `ListView` is unknown since it is dynamic. How do I know where to step checking for `checkBoxNumber.isChecked()`?